# Error detected while processing function <SNR>91_NetrwBrowseChgDir:

Tags: windows, vim

I'm having a problem in Vim whenever I try to open any file.
the error message is:
`Error detected while processing function <SNR>91_NetrwBrowseChgDir`

[image: a screenshot of the Problem]

Any solutions?

Comment: The important error message is only shown in the screenshot. You should add it to the question. Read `:help E303`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general troubleshooting should help here. First, does this only happen when opening the file through netrw, or does is also happen if you use plain `:e /c/xampp/.../register.php`? The error message would suggest it's the latter, so you can then rule out the netrw plugin as the culprit.

Next, read [`:help E303`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/message.txt.html#E303), and investigate where the swap file would be created (the error description already helpful points you to the [`'directory'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27directory%27) option. Check the file system location, and decide whether it's a storage problem (so you need to change access control rights), or a Vim configuration problem (then tell Vim to use a different, writable location for swap files).